# Django doesn't email reporting an internal server error (HTTP status code 500)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I could send mail using the following code

```
E:\Python\django-test\LYYDownloaderServer>python manage.py shell

Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (In
tel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.core.mail import send_mail
>>>
>>> send_mail(
...     'Subject here',
...     'Here is the message.',
...     'redstone-cold@163.com',
...     ['2281570025@qq.com'],
...     fail_silently=False,
... )
1
>>>
```

According to the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/error-reporting/#server-errors):

> When DEBUG is False, Django will email the users listed in the ADMINS
>   setting whenever your code raises an unhandled exception and results
>   in an internal server error (HTTP status code 500). This gives the
>   administrators immediate notification of any errors. The ADMINS will
>   get a description of the error, a complete Python traceback, and
>   details about the HTTP request that caused the error.

but in my case, Django doesn't email reporting an internal server error (HTTP status code 500)
[image]

what's the problem? please help fix the problem

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for LYYDownloaderServer project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/
"""

import os
ADMINS = [('Philip', 'r234327894@163.com'), ('Philip2', '768799875@qq.com')]
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.163.com'  # 'localhost'#'smtp.139.com'
# EMAIL_PORT = 25
# EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'r234327894@163.com'  # '13529123633@139.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '******'
# DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'r234327894@163.com'
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 's4(z8qzt$=x(2t(ok5bb58_!u==+x97t0vpa=*8bb_68baekkh'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']#, '.0letter.com'


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'VideoParser.apps.VideoparserConfig',
    'FileHost.apps.FilehostConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.common.BrokenLinkEmailsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'LYYDownloaderServer.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'LYYDownloaderServer.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

the start of views.py

```
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponse
import logging
import m3u8
import os
from VideoParser.parsers.CommonParsers import *
import urllib.parse
import hashlib
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.db import IntegrityError
from VideoParser.models import *
from importlib import import_module
# print('-------------views --------')
FILES_DIR = 'files'

# specialHostName2module = {'56': 'v56'}
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d %I:%M:%S %p', level=logging.ERROR, handlers=[logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(filename=os.path.join(FILES_DIR, 'LYYDownloaderServer.log'), maxBytes=1024 * 1024, backupCount=1)])
...
```

Comment: set `DEBUG = True` in settings to see what the traceback is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it doesn't matter if you were able to send the mail using the console, but if you received the mail. I assume you did.

Second, it's best to try with exactly the same email address in the console as the one set in the `ADMINS`, just to be sure.

Finally, the sender address might also matter. The default is "root@localhost", and while "root" is OK, "localhost" is not, and some mail servers may refuse the email. Specify another sender email address by setting the `SERVER_EMAIL` Django setting.

Comment: Thanks, SERVER_EMAIL  is essential to this problem , I've written a article about the problem, learn more here http://redstoneleo.blogspot.com/2016/12/email-reporting-exceptions-and-errors_30.html

Answer (score 0):

Djano sends admin emails on error using logging system.

As I can see from your `views.py` you are changing logging settings.
This can be the cause of the problem as you cleared that django admin handler `mail_admins`.

For more information check [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/logging/#topic-logging-parts-handlers)

Answer (score 0):

The [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/error-reporting/#server-errors) says: In order to send email, EMAIL_HOST, EMAIL_HOST_USER and EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD are at the very least needed, but  as I tested, we should also specify SERVER_EMAIL, and only when  SERVER_EMAIL is equal to EMAIL_HOST_USER so can send the email, e.g.

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.163.com'  
SERVER_EMAIL = '234327894-cold@163.com'  # 
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '234327894-cold@163.com'  # 
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '234327894123'  #
```

Django uses [AdminEmailHandler](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/logging/#django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler) to  send an email to the site admins for each log message it receives.
Besides Django,   we could also use Python's 
[logging.handlers.SMTPHandler(mailhost, fromaddr, toaddrs, subject, credentials=None, secure=None, timeout=1.0)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#smtphandler)
to do the same.
For example, put the following code in `views.py`(do change to your account), it will email reporting unhandled exceptions and results in an internal server error (HTTP status code 500).

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d %I:%M:%S %p', handlers=[logging.handlers.SMTPHandler('smtp.163.com', '234327894-cold@163.com', ['234327894-cold@163.com'], 'LYYDownloader Server Exception', credentials=('234327894-cold@163.com', '234327894123'))])
```

Comparing `AdminEmailHandler`  and `SMTPHandler`, I advocate to use `SMTPHandler` whenever possible.
First, `AdminEmailHandler` is Django specific, while you can use  `SMTPHandler` in any Python program, one thing you should care is when using  `SMTPHandler` in client side software,  some  anti-virus software may treat the software as spyware, so you should inform users when your software is about to send email.
Second,  I found email sending by `AdminEmailHandler`  has a bunch  of Information while `SMTPHandler` just send the Python exception Information which makes debugging a bit clear!

Third , If you configure your email within  `settings.py` in Django , there is no exception throw out even If you have made something wrong with the email confirmation ,  while `SMTPHandler` always throw out exception on what's wrong in using .

cite from http://redstoneleo.blogspot.com/2016/12/email-reporting-exceptions-and-errors_30.html