# Why are the error reporting emails not being sent (Django)?

Tags: python, django, email

Python version: 3.6.3
Django version: 3.0.8

I am trying to use enable Django's error reporting via email, but nothing seems to happen when I encounter a 500 error. Here is a copy of my settings file with some comments and sensitive information removed:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = '' # The actual value has been omitted

DEBUG = False
ADMINS = [('', '')] # Omitted. The same email address is used for EMAIL_HOST_USER and SERVER_EMAIL
MANAGERS = ADMINS
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.localhost', '127.0.0.1', '[::1]']
# ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_PSSWORD = '' # Omitted
SERVER_EMAIL = ''

# The logging settings are intentionally commented out. Whether or not they were there seemed to make no difference. Nor did any of the suggested changes I tried.
"""
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
"""

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crispy_forms',
    'main.apps.MainConfig',
    'register.apps.RegisterConfig'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'register.CustomUser'
```

So far, I have tried all the answers from the following:
[Django not sending emails to admins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414130/django-not-sending-emails-to-admins)
[Django not sending error emails - how can I debug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31987569/django-not-sending-error-emails-how-can-i-debug)
[Django doesn't email reporting an internal server error (HTTP status code 500)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41363888/django-doesnt-email-reporting-an-internal-server-error-http-status-code-500)
[Receive django error debug report by email :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61080065/receive-django-error-debug-report-by-email)

None of them seem to have done anything except 2 answers in the last link which caused `ValueError: The ADMINS setting must be a list of 2-tuples`. I do not think the issue is with the email address I am using since I have been using it to send/receive emails through other Python scripts unrelated to Django. I think I am just failing to integrate it properly.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your Logging setting is commented-out

Comment: I added those settings based on advice from the first link, and they did nothing. I made several changes, but nothing ever happened so I commented it out for now while focusing on other areas.

Comment: uncomment those lines and change Logging -> loggers django.request to django

Comment: Nothing seems to have changed, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem - Django server error reporting isn't working. Below are my settings.

```
DEBUG = False
ADMINS = [('Rama', 'rama@domain.com'), ('Bheema', 'bheema@domain.com'),]
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
SERVER_EMAIL = 'somebody@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "somebody@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "<app_password>"
```

Appreciate inputs from anyone who got this working.

Comment: Never mind Django server error reporting. I spent 3+ hours setting it up but couldn't get it to work. Then spent 10 mins to setup Sentry. It's much more insightful.